# How to create routeRules like Nuxt 3 but in Vue 3 + Vite SSR

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vite, server-side-rendering

I'm using Vue.js 3 + Vite 4 in SSR Mode, I saw Nuxt 3 has a configuration option like this

[image]

I'm wondering whether this thing available in Vue 3 + Vite SSR or not ?